# Create React node from string and attach event to a child node

Tags: reactjs

I have a multilanguage string that I obtain from server:

```
const text = 'By clicking on the registration button, you declare that you are of legal age and accept the <a href="#" target="_blank">Legal Conditions</a>.';
```

I need to create a React node jsx from this string and attach an event to the child node.

I have tried the following but I don't know how attach an event to the child node.

```
let textNode = {<span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:text}}/>};
```

Comment: I think the only way to do this would be with vanilla javascript. Something like `window.querySelector('.my-class a');`

Comment: Set a reference on the span (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), after render (useEffect or componentDidMount) use the reference to attach a click event to the anchor. Remember to remove the event before the component unmounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
const text =
  'By clicking on the registration button, you declare that you are of legal age and accept the <a href="#" target="_blank">Legal Conditions</a>.';

const LegalConditions = ({ text }) => {
  const [messageText, linkText, endText] = text.split(/<[a][^>]*>(.+?)<\/[a]>/)

  return <p>{messageText}<a href="#/" onClick={console.log}>{linkText}</a>{endText}</p>;
};
```

Here is a [Condesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-moon-ul3tz)

Comment: Thank you for the solution so much.

Comment: @rapomon Glad that it helped! You can also mark solution as accepted if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, but I will use yours, I think is more elegant :)

```
class LegalLink extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            parts: this.props.message.split(/<[^>]*>*/g)
        }
    }

    render() {
        return <span>{this.state.parts[0]}<a href="/" onClick={this.props.onClick}>{this.state.parts[1]}</a>{this.state.parts[2]}</span>
    }
};
```